# How to keep values inside input fields after generating table while using php post method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I'm trying to figure out how to keep values of input elements inside the boxes after php generates table. Code is listed below.

```
 <form action="zadatak_12-4.php" method="post">
        <label for="nA">Prvi broj: </label>
        <input type="number" id="nA" name="nA">
        <label for="nB">Drugi broj: </label>
        <input type="number" id="nB" name="nB">
        <button type="submit" >Generiraj</button>
    </form><br>
```

Php

```
<?php
    $nA =-1;
    $nB =-1;
    if(isset($_POST['nA'])) $nA = $_POST['nA'];
    if(isset($_POST['nB'])) $nB = $_POST['nB'];
    
    if(!is_numeric($nA)) $nA = -1;
    if(!is_numeric($nB)) $nB = -1;

    if(($nA != -1)&&($nB !=-1))
    {
        $odBroj = $nA; $doBroj = $nB;
        if($nB > $nA) { $odBroj = $nB; $doBroj = $nA;}
            $pom  ="<table class='tablica'>";
            $pom .="<tr><th>Broj</th><th>Kvadrat</th><th>Alert poruka</th></tr>";
            
            for ($i = $odBroj; $i >= $doBroj; $i--)
            {
            $pom .= "<tr><td>".$i."</td><td>".($i*$i)."</td><td><span class='glumiLink'>Poruka</span></td></tr>";
            }
            $pom .="</table>";
        } else {
            $pom  ="<p>Pogrešno uneseni ili nedefinirani parametri!</p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I added `value="<?php echo ($_POST['nA']); ?>"` in HTML input element.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to use error control operator (@) in such cases.

```
value="<?php echo @$_POST['nA']; ?>"
```

Comment: Suppressing errors is a very bad practice. And calling it "good" is an outright fallacy